# Is it possible to mock out all methods on an object easily in PHPUnit?

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit

Is it possible to mock out any method calls on a stub and have it return the same response?

I'm looking to do something like this:

```
$mock->expects($this->any())
    ->method($this->any())
    ->willReturn($mock);
```

I realize that this isn't a best practice, but I already have this section of code covered.  All the methods that actually get called should return the object itself too.

I've tried the above example and not adding the call to method. Neither worked and I can't find anything in the documentation.